# How to avoid duplicates when donated using different email address or spelling mistake on names?

Tags: civicontribute

Its very often happening for my donors, that they donate first with an email and then next time with another. or some spelling mistake on name or email address. 
Civicrm then creates duplicates of that person.
Although I can merge those 2 contacts, how can we avoid/reduce this kind of instances?

Answer (score 4):

That is a difficult area. It touches on'the safest system is the one without users' :-) You can not avoid users making typos as far as I know, you will need to have a regular deduplication process in place. Here is the process we are discussing at one of my projects:

- we want the data in the system asap, so we accept everything but all new contacts go in a separate group
- we have a daily process for one of the employees, looking for dedupes on a daily basis (with a fairly strict rule first and a more fuzzy one second) and taking corrective action whenever required. If new contact is fine it is removed from the group.
  I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have repeat donors, you can include the option (or requirement) to create an account in the Advanced section of the Profile you use on the Contribution page (at least with Drupal):

[image: Profiles Advanced Settings]

This provides the benefit of allowing them to log in and have the forms prefilled to avoid typos, and also gives them the benefit of having access to a Contact Dashboard with their donation history on it.

If you are sending emails that they are responding to with donations, you can also use Checksum links through CiviMail to send them to the form with their information prefilled. [From the book](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/tokens-and-mail-merge/):

> A particularly useful token is the checksum. The checksum allows you to give people links to  contribution forms, profiles, petitions, and event registration forms that are prefilled with information that is already in their contact record.   The image [below] shows an example of this.
>
> [image: Checksum Token]
>
> Only contact fields and actions can be inserted in your email as tokens. Related records, such as the name of the event for which the contacts have pending enrollments, cannot be included. However, you could provide a link to the person's contact dashboard so that they can review their registration details for themselves (once logged in), or you could use a checksum token to allow access to a profile through which they can modify their information without having to log in.
>
> Go to this page for further details on using the checksum token: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Universal problem - issues with typo do happen always

Easier way to avoid this issue is by providing a username and password by this way you force the user to login which will avoid duplication. Also, you can provide rules which will allow the user to access limited pages